# Aligning three divs side by side without flexbox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm having a hard time aligning three divs side by side. I managed to get it to work in Chrome, but as soon as I tested other browsers it went all to hell.

I need the first div to take up 100% of available space, the second div has static width (160px), and the third div needs to be width: auto, depending on the content size inside (But I can technically make it work with a static width as well).

This is what I have tried:

```
.row {
  display: table;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

You can see the whole code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLjGab

As you see, this works without nay problems in Chrome, but in other browsers as soon as I put any content within the col the height of the row is bigger than defined, and I'm having a really hard time finding out why.

I need this to work in IE9 as well, so flexbox is a no go, but it would be awesome if someone could at least point me in the correct direction of how this could be accomplished.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just needed to add `vertical-align: middle;` to he column, and that fixed it.